# Cannot import Flask-Paginate

Tags: python, flask

I installed Flask-Paginate using pip, but when I try to import it I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'Paginate'`.  How do I import this?

```
$ pip install -U flask-paginate
```

```
>>> from flask import Paginate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Paginate'
```

The package also isn't recognized in PyCharm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't import it from `flask`, it's not part of Flask.  Import it from `flask_paginate`, the module you installed.  It's also called `Pagination`.

The [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/#how-to-use) show how to import it (although they are using the [deprecated](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1135) `flask.ext` notation).

```
from flask_paginate import Pagination
```

Configure the project interpreter in PyCharm to point to the virtualenv you installed the package to.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [`flask-paginate` docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/#how-to-use):

```
from flask.ext.paginate import Pagination
```

However, `flask.ext` is [removed](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/pull/1484). Use this instead:

```
from flask_paginate import Pagination
```

Answer (score 0):

if anything above works use in VSCode it helps:

py -m pip install Flask-Paginate

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).